# How to set the maximum size for a folder?

Tags: c#

How could I limit the size for a folder on a USB drive? For example, if I set 5 MB for the size of a folder then I could not copy over 5 MB data to this folder.

Comment: I dont think you can. You could do it by partitioning the drive though

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this on a per-folder basis with the functionality built into the operating system. You can do it (*as long as the device is formatted to NTFS*) with drive quotas **at the level of the whole drive/partition**

Some further reading on drive quotas:

- [Reading quota information on an NTFS volume](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DiskQuota.aspx).
- [How can I query NTFS  disk quotas in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771968/how-can-i-query-ntfs-disk-quotas-in-c)

The only other way you could do this would be by writing some form of [File System Filter driver](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/fs-filter-driver-tutorial.aspx?msg=3473872), but this isn't something that's achievable at present in managed code.